# Where is Plutarch Heavensbee originally from?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In the Hunger Games trilogy, there is no mention of where Plutarch Heavensbee is originally from. Are there any clues that I might have missed in the books about whether he is from the Capitol or one of the districts?

My guess would be that he isn't from the Capitol because he doesn't seem to be very sympathetic with its vision.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it is not specifically stated, it can be inferred that he is from the Capitol.  The games are specifically designed as a punishment and reminder to the Districts of their failed rebellion.  If they were to allow a resident of a district be a part of the games administrators, and particularly at its highest rank, would open all kinds of opportunities to subvert the games.  Basically, Capitol citizens are the only people who could be trusted to run the games.

That being said, there are several cases where the general citizens of the Capitol are shown to not be entirely on-board with the games and the treatment of the Districts.  Plutarch certainly, and the handful of others that assist in the planning and execution of extracting Katniss to District 13.  A large number of Capitol citizens lose their love for the games in *Catching Fire*, when they realize that the Victors they have come to know and love are going back into the games.  Suddenly it is not some disconnected group of children from the districts they have no concern for, instead it is Victors they have come to know and love and think of as their own.

Comment: Your answer is literally ten seconds behind mine. That's the closest ninja I've ever been a part of.

Answer (score 13):

Characters from the Capitol are consistently given Roman names.

- [Plutarch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch)
- [Caesar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar)
- [Octavia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octavia_the_Younger)
- [Flavius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavius)
- [Seneca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seneca_the_Younger)

This pattern suggest that, based on his name, we are to believe that Plutarch Heavensbee is from the Capitol.

Although it is interesting to note that the actual Plutarch was a Greek who was given Roman citizenship.

Comment: Yet some characters from wealthy districts are also given Roman names, like Cato from District 2.

Comment: I think the Heavensbees (in Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes) were from the capital. In fact, he might be a descendant of one of the mentors.

Answer (score 3):

While it's probably safe to assume that [Plutarch](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Plutarch_Heavensbee) is from District 13, given his role in the rebellion, there is no direct mention of his birthplace. Capitol seems the most likely alternative to 13, but he could have been recruited for the rebellion from any District.

Comment: I agree. He could be from one of the Capitol's favoured districts, namely 1,2 or 3

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. Coin refers to him as a "welcome guest" in District 13, definitely not a native.