# In the world of The Hunger Games, can people move to a different district?

Tags: the-hunger-games

The Hunger Games take place in an area of the world that is divided into 13 districts, all of them subserviant to the Capitol. Each of these districts offer a different "service" to the Capitol, whether that be coal or fish.

Is there any information on citizens of the Districts moving from one District to another, either when travelling or more permanently (i.e. moving home)? If so, could citizens move to the Capitol?

Comment: Related, dupe of your sub-question: [Are non-citizens of the Capitol permitted to permanently immigrate?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/52630/5184)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. The Capitol might relocate or reassign someone to another district but there's no travel between districts for most people.

*The Hunger Games* (first book), Part I, Ch. 3:

> The speed initially takes my breath away. Of course, I’ve never been
>   on a train, as **travel between the districts is forbidden except for
>   officially sanctioned duties.** For us, that’s mainly transporting coal.
>   But this is no ordinary coal train. It’s one of the high-speed Capitol
>   models that average 250 miles per hour. Our journey to the Capitol
>   will take less than a day.

Comment: I wonder how much of this is enforced in the richer, tribute districts.